# Possible to relocate submit button to bottom of my form?

Tags: php, forms

I'm pretty new to PHP and having a problem with my form.  As it is now it works, but I need to relocate the submit button to the bottom of the page. Appreciate it if anyone knows if and how this might be done.

**MY HTML**

```
<head>
<meta content="en-us" http-equiv="Content-Language" />
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>CALIFORNIA SCHOOL OF LAW APPLICA</title>
<style type="text/css">
.auto-style1 {
    color: #000080;
}
.auto-style3 {
    text-align: center;
}
.auto-style4 {
    font-size: large;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align: left;
}
.auto-style5 {
    font-size: small;
}
.auto-style6 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: large;
}
.auto-style7 {
    font-size: xx-small;
}
.auto-style8 {
    font-size: large;
}
.auto-style9 {
    font-size: small;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.auto-style10 {
    color: #000000;
}
</style>
</head>
<form method="post" action="contact.php">
<body>

 <p>
<img alt="California School Of Law Logo" height="116" src="LogoFinal%20no%20text.jpg" width="162" /></p>
<div id="layer1" class="auto-style3" style="position: absolute; width: 347px; height: 52px; z-index: 1; left: 368px; top: 53px">
    <span class="auto-style6">CALIFORNIA SCHOOL OF LAW</span><br class="auto-style6" />
    <span class="auto-style6">APPLICATION</span></div>
<hr class="auto-style1" style="height: 4px" />
<div id="layer2" class="auto-style4" style="position: absolute; width: 397px; height: 380px; z-index: 2; left: 76px; top: 170px">
    <strong>Personal Information<br />
    <br />
    </strong><span class="auto-style5">Last Name:
    <input name="Text1" type="text" /><br />
    <br />
    First Name:&nbsp; <input name="Text2" type="text" /> M.I:
    <input name="Text3" style="width: 15px" type="text" /><br />
    <br />
    Name on acedemic records (if different from above) <br />
    <input name="Text4" style="width: 227px" type="text" /><br />
    <br />
    Social Security Number:&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input name="SS" size="9" style="width: 141px" type="text" 

/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&

nbsp;
    <br />
    <br />
    DL State:<select name="Select1">
    <option></option>
    <option value="CA">CA</option>
    <option>NV</option>
    <option>TX</option>
    </select> DL Number: <input name="Text5" type="text" /><br />
    <br />
    Gender:&nbsp;&nbsp; <select name="Select2">
    <option></option>
    <option>Male</option>
    <option>Female</option>
    </select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
    Date of birth:&nbsp; <input name="Text6" style="width: 92px" type="text" /><br />
    <br />
    Ethnic/Racial Background:&nbsp; <select name="Select3">
    <option></option>
    <option>Caucasian</option>
    <option>Hispanic</option>
    <option>Asian</option>
    <option>African American</option>
    <option>Other</option>
    </select><br />
    <br />
    Birth place:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input name="Text7" type="text" /><br />
    </span></div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div id="layer9" class="auto-style9" style="position: absolute; width: 518px; height: 230px; z-index: 9; left: 537px; top: 

1022px">
    D. Have you ever been court marshaled?&nbsp; <select name="Select14">
    <option></option>
    <option>YES</option>
    <option>NO</option>
    </select><br />
    <br />
    E. Have you ever been dishonorably disharged<br />
    from Miltary service?&nbsp; <select name="Select15">
    <option></option>
    <option>YES</option>
    <option>NO</option>
    </select><br />
    <br />
    F. Do you know of any matter which might otherwise adversly affect your 
    admissions to law school or the state bar?&nbsp; <select name="Select16">
    <option></option>
    <option>YES</option>
    <option>NO</option>
    </select><br />
    <br />

&nbsp;


</div>
<div id="layer8" class="auto-style8" style="position: absolute; width: 520px; height: 307px; z-index: 8; left: 11px; top: 949px">
    <strong>Miscellaneous<br />
    <br />
    </strong><span class="auto-style9">Please answer the following questions, if 
    you answer YES to any question please explain<br />
    <br />
    A. Have you ever been on probation, suspended, dismissed or formally 
    reprimanded by any educational institution?&nbsp; <select name="Select11">
    <option></option>
    <option>YES</option>
    <option>NO</option>
    </select><br />
    <br />
    B.&nbsp; Have you ever been convicted, pleaded guilty or no contest to any 
    crime other than a minor traffic violation or juvenile offense?
    <select name="Select12">
    <option></option>
    <option>YES</option>
    <option>NO</option>
    </select><br />
    <br />
    C. Are there any criminal charges currently pending or expected against you?
    <select name="Select13">
    <option></option>
    <option>YES</option>
    <option>NO</option>
    </select><br />
    <br />
    Explanation: <br />
&nbsp;</span>
</div>
<div id="layer7" style="position: absolute; width: 1162px; height: 24px; z-index: 7; left: 9px; top: 922px">
    <strong><span class="auto-style5">
    <hr class="auto-style1" style="height: 4px" /></span></strong></div>
<div id="layer6" style="position: absolute; width: 415px; height: 205px; z-index: 6; left: 462px; top: 644px">
    Email Address: <input name="Text18" style="width: 229px" type="text" /><br />
    <br />
    In case of emergency:<br />
    <br />
    Name: <input name="Text19" type="text" /><br />
    <br />
    Relationship: <input name="Text20" type="text" /><br />
    <br />
    Phone:&nbsp; <input name="Text21" type="text" /></div>
<div id="layer5" class="auto-style6" style="position: absolute; width: 431px; height: 278px; z-index: 5; left: 10px; top: 643px">
    <strong>Contact Information<br />
    <br />
    </strong><span class="auto-style5">Street Address:</span><strong>
    <input name="Text12" type="text" /><br />
    <br />
    </strong><span class="auto-style5">City:<strong>&nbsp;
    <input name="Text13" type="text" /><br />
    <br />
    </strong>State:<strong>&nbsp;&nbsp; <select name="Select10">
    <option></option>
    <option>CA</option>
    <option>CO</option>
    <option>TX</option>
    <option>NV</option>
    <option>WA</option>
    </select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </strong>ZIP:<strong>&nbsp;
    <input name="Text14" type="text" /><br />
    <br />
    </strong>Home Ph:<strong> <input name="Text15" type="text" /><br />
    <br />
    </strong>Work Ph<strong>: <input name="Text16" type="text" /><br />
    <br />
    </strong>Cell Ph:<strong> <input name="Text17" type="text" /><br />
    </strong></span></div>
<div id="layer4" style="position: absolute; width: 1174px; height: 31px; z-index: 4; left: 5px; top: 610px">
    <strong><span class="auto-style5">
    <hr class="auto-style10" style="height: 4px" /></span></strong></div>
<div id="layer3" class="auto-style6" style="position: absolute; width: 446px; height: 422px; z-index: 3; left: 671px; top: 

165px">
    <strong>Status - Term Start 14WIN<br />
    <br />
    </strong><span class="auto-style5">Application Status:<strong>
    <select name="Select4">
    <option></option>
    <option>New Student</option>
    <option>Returning Student</option>
    </select><br />
    <br />
    </strong>Prior Application Submitted?:<strong> <select name="Select5">
    <option></option>
    <option>YES</option>
    <option>NO</option>
    </select><br />
    <br />
    </strong>LSAC Registration No.: <strong>&nbsp;
    <input name="Text8" type="text" /></strong></span><br />
    <br />
    <span class="auto-style5">Have you taken the LSAT?:&nbsp;
    <select name="Select6">
    <option></option>
    <option>NO</option>
    <option>YES</option>
    </select>&nbsp;&nbsp; Score:
    <input name="Text9" style="width: 71px" type="text" /><br />
    <br />
    Are your transcripts on file with LSAC? : <select name="Select7">
    <option></option>
    <option>YES</option>
    <option>NO</option>
    </select><br />
    <br />
    </span><em><span class="auto-style7"><strong>Note: You do not have to be a 
    U.S. Citizen to attend law school or practice law in California<br />
    <br />
    </strong></span></em><span class="auto-style5">Are you a United States 
    Citizen? :<strong> <em><span class="auto-style7">
    <select name="Select8" style="width: 24px">
    <option>YES</option>
    <option>NO</option>
    </select></span></em><br />
    <br />
    </strong>If NO, are you a permanent resident? :<strong>
    <select name="Select9">
    <option></option>
    <option>YES</option>
    <option>NO</option>
    </select><br />
    <br />
    </strong>VISA Type:<strong>
    <input name="Text10" style="width: 166px" type="text" /><br />
    <br />
    </strong>Alien Number:<strong>&nbsp; </strong></span>
    <input name="Text11" style="width: 178px" type="text" /></div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<tr><td colspan=2 align=center><input type=submit name="send" value="Submit"></td></tr> 
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Sorry.  Guess I need to find a different forum for newbies such as myself.  Just cant figure out how to do this so far.  Seems like I am so close to having this working...yet so far!

Comment: What's the purpose of the form? If you eliminate the 'mailto' choices there isn't much left...

Comment: question is a bit vague. What button? The html is incomplete. Table elements without table. What mailto do you want to eliminate?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you included only a snippet of your HTML page. For submitting the form you could use something like `<input type="submit" />`. If you always want to send to the same email address, you could edit your PHP: `$to = "jeff@vegaspchelp.com";`.

Of if you want a different email address based on the selected option, you could edit your code as follows:

**HTML**

```
 <select name="sendto"> 
    <option>General</option> 
    <option>Support</option> 
    <option>Sales</option> 
 </select>
```

**PHP: contact.php**

```
<?php
$emailAddresses = array(
    "General" => "jeff@vegaspchelp.com",
    "Support" => "jeff@vegaspchelp.com",
    "Sales"   => "sales@mycompany.com"
);
$to = $emailAddresses[$_REQUEST['sendto']];
```

You will likely want to also include some additional input validation in your PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="send">
```

to

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="send" style="position: absolute; z-index: 3; left: 500px; top:   1250px">
```